# Ghidra Headless Analyzer - Create Functions

Tags: python, ghidra

I'm interested in open a binary file (`.bin`, without arch info), and analyze it with `analyzeHeadless.bat` (Ghidra version without GUI).

I know what is the architecture of the file, so I pass it as a flag to the analyzer.

My command line is:
`analyzeHeadless.bat  <project_location>  <project_name> -import <my_file> -processor <my_known_processor> -postscript <my_script.py> -scriptPath <path>`

my_script.py is:

```
for block in getMemoryBlocks():
    current = block.getStart().getOffset()
    end = block.getEnd().getOffset()
    addr = currentProgram.getAddressFactory().getAddress(hex(current).replace('L', ''))
    disassemble(addr)
    current +=1

func = getFirstFunction()
print("First func is:    " + str(func))
```

I try to disassemble every address (looks like Ghigra doesn't do it itself), and after that I want to print the first function.

The problem is:
`func` appears to be `None`.

But if after the headless execution I open the project in the GUI `Ghidra`, and execute:

```
func = getFirstFunction()
print("First func is:    " + str(func))
```

It works and gets me the function.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong? I guess there is some analysis that runs in the background and created the functions. How can I run it in my python script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution that I found is:

`analyze(currentProgram)`

Just after the disassembly.